# DRF: router for ViewSet with a foreign-key lookup_field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Using Django REST Framework 3.12.4, I cannot properly get the URLs for a ViewSet to work if that ViewSet has a foreign-key lookup field.

I have the following in `models.py`:

```py
class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=191, unique=True)


class Token(rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    domain_policies = models.ManyToManyField(Domain, through='TokenDomainPolicy')


class TokenDomainPolicy(models.Model):
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['token', 'domain'], name='unique_entry')]
```

In `views.py`, I have:

```py
class TokenDomainPolicyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'domain__name'
    serializer_class = serializers.TokenDomainPolicySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.TokenDomainPolicy.objects.filter(token_id=self.kwargs['id'], token__user=self.request.user)
```

You can see from `TokenDomainPolicyViewSet.lookup_field` that I would like to be able to query the `-detail` endpoint by using the related `Domain`'s `name` field instead of its primary key. (`name` is unique for a given token.)

I thought this can be done with `lookup_field = 'domain__name'`.

However, it doesn't quite work. Here's my `urls.py`:

```py
tokens_router = SimpleRouter()
tokens_router.register(r'', views.TokenViewSet, basename='token')

tokendomainpolicies_router = SimpleRouter()
tokendomainpolicies_router.register(r'', views.TokenDomainPolicyViewSet, basename='token_domain_policies')

auth_urls = [
    path('tokens/', include(tokens_router.urls)),  # for completeness only; problem persists if removed
    path('tokens/<id>/domain_policies/', include(tokendomainpolicies_router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include(auth_urls)),
]
```

The list endpoint works fine (e.g. `/auth/tokens/6f82e9bc-46b8-4719-b99f-2dc0da062a02/domain_policies/`); it returns a list of serialized `TokenDomainPolicy` objects.

However, let's say there is a `Domain` object with `name = 'test.net'` related to this `Token`. I would think I can GET `/auth/tokens/6f82e9bc-46b8-4719-b99f-2dc0da062a02/domain_policies/test.net/` to retrieve this object, but the result is 404.

Additional observations:

- It nearly **does** work if I set `lookup_field = 'domain'`. However, this leads to URLs that contain the `Domain`'s ID (like `.../25/`) which is not what I want. But based on this, I conclude that the `-detail` endpoint does get routed in principle.
- It **does** work if I add an explicit override like

  ```py
    path('tokens/<id>/domain_policies/<domain__name>/', views.TokenDomainPolicyViewSet.as_view(
        {'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'}
    ), name='token_domain_policies-detail'),
  ```

  However, why would it be necessarily to explicitly bind the methods like this? (It's not necessary if `lookup_field` does not specify a foreign-key lookup!)
- Weirdest of all, if I install `django_extensions` and run `manage.py show_urls`, the `-detail` endpoint URL shows up with the **correct** `<domain__name>` URL kwarg, even **without** the override from the previous bullet. If I add the override, the corresponding line in the output is displayed twice as an **identical duplicate**.

  How can it be that the set of known URLs remains unchanged with or without the override, but in one case the endpoint works as expected, and in the other case the response is 404?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`docs`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter), the default match lookup will ignore slashes and period characters, that's why `test.name` can't be found:

> The router will match lookup values containing any characters except slashes and period characters.

You can find it in the [`source`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L221) as well:

> ```
> lookup_value = getattr(viewset, 'lookup_value_regex', '[^/.]+')
> ```

So to fix, just change the `lookup_value_regex` to allow periods in the viewset's lookup:

```
class TokenDomainPolicyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'domain__name'
    lookup_value_regex = '[^/]+'
```